# Equivalent of XmlReaderSettings.ValidationType.None in .NET Standard 1.6

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, .net-core, .net-standard

Trying to port an app from .NET 4.5 to .NET Standard 1.6 but I see that [XmlReaderSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationtype(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have the ValidationType enum present. Is there another way to do this? Would I be able to easily create a custom XmlReader to achieve the same thing? I want to set it to None.

Cheers.

Comment: http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/xmlschema-in-net-core/507/2

Comment: Looks like .NET core does not support schema validation yet, and in the full framework `None` (<=> no validation) is actually the default. So everything should just work like you want it, doesn't it?  In your code simple remove the line assigning the validation type (or guard it with proper `#if/#endif` blocks).

Comment: Ah. Right you are. I forgot to remove a namespace placed there by the XSD converter and I mistook this for the validation being different :)